# How to properly give apache access to a website user's /home/websiteuser/html directory?

Tags: apache, permissions

Setup:

- Websites are setup as users in `/home/`
- Website users restricted to home directories as `/home/websiteuser/` is
  owned by root
- Website users are part of the `websites` group
- `www-data` is part of the `websites` group
- Virtual host points to: `/home/websiteuser/html/`
- `/home/websiteuser/html/` is set to `-R 755`
- Files inside `/html/` are owned by `websiteuser:websites`
- Website user is used to access website via sftp

Everything works great except apache requires us to recursively `chmod 777` the `/home/websiteuser/html/files/` directory or images won’t display and the CMS can’t write it’s mysql backups.

The website user owns the files so the sftp access works but do I have to make `www-data` own the files - or is there a way where sftp login works and apache can still have access as well?

We've seen many questions around this but don’t understand the answers sorry - any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've solved this by making a "websites" group and adding the apache user (www-data) to this group like this (must be done as root - switch to root with `$ su root` or use `sudo` in front of the commands like this `$ sudo useradd username`:

- Add a new group - this will be the name of the group used for all websites:

`$ addgroup websites`

- List groups to check it was created

`$ getent websites`

- Add the apache user to the websites-group so apache has access to run the websites

`$ usermod -G websites www-data`

- Check www-data is part of the websites-group:

`$ grep '^ websites' /etc/group`

- Add a new website user (this will be the user used to run the website)

`$ useradd username`

- Give the user a password

`$ passwd username`

- Follow the prompts to add a password
- Add website user to websites group

`$ usermod -G websites username`

- Create a new directory for the user to serve websites from:

`$ mkdir /home/username`

- The owner of the website directory must be root or sftp will fail
- Make root the owner and group of website user’s home directory:

`$ chown root:websites /home/username`

- Give website user limited access to their home directory:

`$ chmod 750 /home/username`

- Move into the website user’s directory:

`$ cd /home/username`

- Make a web root directory (this is the opublic directory where the website's files will live):

`$ mkdir html`

- Give website user owner:group on web root:

`$ chown username:websites html`

- Change permissions on the html directory:

`$ chmod 750 html`

- Copy all the website's files into the `html` directory
- Recursively set ownership on all files within the web-root

`$ chown -R username:ssb-websites html`

- Recursively set premissions on all files within the web-root (owner and group have read, write, execute permissions):

`$ chmod -R 770 html`

- Recursively set permissions on all files within web-root:

`$ chmod 644 $(find . ! -type d)`

- If having issues, make sure directory permissions are set like this (the top-level website directory `/home/username/` must be owned by root or sFTP access won't work):

`/home/username | drwxr-x--- | root:websites`

`/home/username/html | drwxr-x--- | username:websites`

`/home/username/html/directories/ | drwxrwx--- | username:websites`

`/home/username/html/files.html | -rw-r--r-- | username:websites`

We're designers so this is the way we worked it out, if anyone can see improvements, feel free to edit!